# I can't pass picture from my Mock data to component ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[mock.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRUDx.png)[example photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bOx3.png)

as you can see at the photo. I have a problem with passing my photos to component. I dont want to import my photo at the component. I want to take photos from mock.js but they do not appear at localhost. How can I get through this ?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React from "react";
import "./style.scss";

import { IoIosRadioButtonOn } from "react-icons/io";

export default function requestCard(props) {
  return (
    <div className="Card">
      <div className="Card-Top">
        <div className="Top-Left">
          <IoIosRadioButtonOn />
          <h4 contentEditable="true">{props.data.Status}</h4>
        </div>
        <div className="Top-Right">
          <h4>{props.data.Date}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="Card-Middle">
        <h2>{props.data.CutStyle}</h2>
        <p>{props.data.client}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="Card-Bottom">
        <img src={props.data.Picture} alt="" />
        <h2>{props.data.name}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code as text? It's much easier to work with then.

Comment: Of course, I edit my post and add the code.